# Multi-user support with nhibernate winforms application

Tags: winforms, nhibernate

I’m working on a multi-user winforms application (MDI). Our application uses NHibernate and one session per instance.

The problem is if an user makes modification, for example a user adds an item to a list, another user doesn’t see this modification immediately. How do I get around this, what is the recommended approach? Should I be using One-session-per-form or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Every application needs to define it's own unit of work. For your use case, if you are wanting the database to update every time a user adds an item to a list, then that should be your unit of work.

So to answer your question for your unique use case, I would create a new NHibernate session, persist the users changes, and dispose of the session every time a user adds an item to the list.

FYI: You should not feel that there is anything wrong with creating a session per user action if that is indeed the behavior your application desires. Typically in a WinForms application, most people do use a Session-per-Form pattern but then again, that is because most WinForms applications fall into the model of having a form that the user needs to complete before proceeding to the next form. In those cases, you would only want to persist/save the user's changes when they submit the form. But if you application does not fall into that model, then your definition of a unit of work ( session life-cycle ) could be completely different.